# pure Javascript and jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a tabbed menu with an arrow below that should move when I click on a specific tab.I am using pure JavaScript for the tabs and jQuery to move the arrow. The problem is that this works only when I delete one of the scripts. If I delete the jQuery script, the tabs are working and viceversa. Has anyone any idea what the problem may be? Here is the HTML

```
<div class="item active">
    <ul class="tabbed-menu menu-list">
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_1', 'content_1');" id="tb_1" class="tabmenu active">Consultanță IT</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_2', 'content_2');" id="tb_2" class="tabmenu">Managementul Relațiilor cu Clienții</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_3', 'content_3');" id="tb_3" class="tabmenu">Business Intelligence</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_4', 'content_4');" id="tb_4" class="tabmenu">Turism și Ospitalitate</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_5', 'content_5');" id="tb_5" class="tabmenu">Finanțe și Bănci</a></li>
        <li><a class="right carousel-control" href="#services-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">Mai multe <img src="images/right-arrow.png" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
</div> <!--/.item active-->

<div class="item">
    <ul class="tabbed-menu menu-list">
        <li><a class="left carousel-control" href="#services-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><img src="images/left-arrow.png" alt="">Inapoi</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_6', 'content_6');" id="tb_6" class="tabmenu">Educatie</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_7', 'content_7');" id="tb_7" class="tabmenu">eCommerce</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_8', 'content_8');" id="tb_8" class="tabmenu">eLearning</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_9', 'content_9');" id="tb_9" class="tabmenu">Website</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:rudrSwitchTab('tb_10', 'content_10');" id="tb_10" class="tabmenu">mCommerce</a></li>    
    </ul>
</div> <!--/.item-->`
```

Javascript

```
function rudrSwitchTab(rudr_tab_id, rudr_tab_content) {
// first of all we get all tab content blocks
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = 'none'; // hide all tab content
    }
    document.getElementById(rudr_tab_content).style.display = 'block'; // display the content of the tab we need

    // now we get all tab menu items by class names (use the next code only if you need to highlight current tab)
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabmenu");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = 'tabmenu'; 
    }
    document.getElementById(rudr_tab_id).className = 'tabmenu active';
}
```

and jQ

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.menu-list li' ).click(function(event) {
        var position = $(this).position();
        var width    = Math.round($(this).width()/2) - 5;

        // alert(width);

        $(".arrow-marker").css('left', 'auto').stop().transition({ x: position.left  + width });
        event.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

Has anyone any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: why not use jquery (or not use jquery) for everything? can you add a jsfiddle

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? If not please check and update your question description with the error report.

Comment: Can you edit the post so that the code is correctly structured? Use the {} icon in the toolbar.

Comment: Welcome! Before asking in the future, please learn to properly format code on SO. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: Can you make a full fiddle?

Comment: @connexo Thank you :)

Comment: You are using `event.preventDefault();` in your jQuery which basically prevents the link to follow its `href`. So the javascript you have put in your links' `href` will **not** be executed - this is exactly what `event.preventDefault();` is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @connexo simple as that! Thank you ! I'm newbie at JS ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `event.preventDefault();` in your jQuery which basically prevents the link to follow its `href`. So the javascript you have put in your links' `href` will not be executed - this is exactly what event.**preventDefault**(); is supposed to **prevent**. Sort of a name that fits :)

Answer (score 0):

First please check error in console. If it is jquery conflict error.
Use these below line before start the jquery code.

```
$.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Jquery no conflict

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

see here to catch info of this function

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="tabbed-menu menu-list">
    <li><a href="#" id="tb_1" tab-id='content_1' class="tabmenu active">Consultanță IT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="tb_2" tab-id='content_2' class="tabmenu">Managementul Relațiilor cu Clienții</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="tb_3" tab-id='content_3' class="tabmenu">Business Intelligence</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="tb_4" tab-id='content_4' class="tabmenu">Turism și Ospitalitate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="tb_5" tab-id='content_5' class="tabmenu">Finanțe și Bănci</a></li>
    <li><a class="right carousel-control" href="#services-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">Mai multe <img src="images/right-arrow.png" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

I made these changes

```
rudrSwitchTab($(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('tab-id'));
    event.preventDefault();
```

And now it all works